# Upgrade from Megento 2.0.2 fails "An error has happened during application run. See exception log for details."

Tags: magento, upgrade

Magento 2.0.2 on CentOS using Bitnami stack. Followed command line upgrade using Composer.

Trying to load the shop front after upgrade (followed steps without errors) results in the error above. The /var/log/exception.log file shows:-

```
[2016-06-09 15:18:04] main.CRITICAL: exception 'Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException' with message 'Source class "" for "Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor" generation does not exist.' in /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Code/Generator.php:171
Stack trace:
0 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Code/Generator.php(100): Magento\Framework\Code\Generator->tryToLoadSourceClass('Magento\\Framewo...', Object(Magento\Framework\Interception\Code\Generator\Interceptor))
1 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Code/Generator/Autoloader.php(35): Magento\Framework\Code\Generator->generateClass('Magento\\Framewo...')
2 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Code\Generator\Autoloader->load('Magento\\Framewo...')
3 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(105): spl_autoload_call('Magento\\Framewo...')
4 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(88): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
5 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(130): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\Framewo...')
6 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(67): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->get('Magento\\Framewo...')
7 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(57): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
8 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Bootstrap.php(233): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
9 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/index.php(38): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\\Framewo...')
10 {main} [] []
}
```

Checked permissions and cleared var/cache manually, but to no avail.

Any ideas how I can resolve this error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should help:

```
cd <your magento root>
rm -Rf var/generation/* var/di/*
bin/magento cache:clean
```

Answer (score 1):

for ubuntu:
1) goto var/www/html/magento(Root Folder where your magento is) or in htdocs if you have installed lampp.
2) sudo rm -Rf var/generation
3) sudo bin/magento cache:clean
4) sudo bin/magento cache:flush

Done.....