# "An error has happened during application run." error while installing Magento 2.1.2 with sample data

Tags: magento, exception, error-handling, installation

I've uploaded Magento 2.1.2 CE on my server and want to install it. But after one minute, I get this error:

> An error has happened during application run. See exception log for
>   details.

This is everything I have. Not log is inserted in the log files. I also tried to use the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37730260/upgrade-from-megento-2-0-2-fails-an-error-has-happened-during-application-run) but it could not sovle my problem.
Please help me ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: @Enigmativity sorry for it. I did not know Magento has a dedicated section in StackExchange. You were right ...

Comment: look in var>log>exception.log & post the error code

Comment: I am having the same issue, as mentionned in the comment, nothing gets logged in exception.log, the bug does not exist in developer mode for me its only when I am in production mode

Answer (score 1):

Clear cache
Run this code
sudo php bin/magento cache:clean
sudo php bin/magento cache:flush